# Number of ways of getting 3-digit even number using 0,1,2,3,4,5

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

1) How many 3-digit numbers can be formed by using $0,1,2,3,4,5$ ? Using basics it would be $ 5 \times 5 \times4 = 100$

2) How many 3-digit numbers can be formed by  $8,1,2,3,4,5$ which are even? Again using basics we get $ 4 \times 5 \times 3 =60$

3)  Now I want to ask how many 3 digit numbers can be formed which are even using $0,1,2,3,4,5$?

No repetition is allowed in all above cases. Here I am not getting how to use basics when we need to apply both conditions of case 1 and case 2  (i.e when we need to take care of both things  zero at hundredth place and even number at unit place) simultaneously .

Comment: For the first part, if the only restriction is no repetition, then the total amount of 3-digit numbers out of 6 digits is $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 120$

Answer (score 1):

Without repetition counting the number of 3digit numbers using digits from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$:

---

Count the number of $3$-digit *strings* whose last digit is even.

- Pick the last digit: $3$ options
- Pick the first digit: $5$ options
- Pick the second digit: $4$ options

$3\times 5\times 4 = 60$ total

Remove from that the number of $3$-digit strings whose last digit is even and first digit is $0$

- First digit is zero: $1$ option
- Pick the last digit: $2$ options
- Pick the second digit: $4$ options

$1\times 2\times 4=8$ total that were "bad" and should not have been counted in the first if we wanted to count numbers instead of strings

This gives $60-8=52~~~$ $3$-digit even numbers using digits from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ without repetition.

Answer (score 0):

We want 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 in the hundreds digit - 5 choices, anything in the tens digit - 6 choices, and 0, 2 or 4 in the units digit - 3 choices. We have 5*6*3=90 numbers at the moment.

Now for the no repetition condition:

First we exclude odd digit-repeated odd digit-even digit numbers, 9 of these; and odd digit-even digit-repeated even digit numbers, another 9; also we exclude even digit-odd digit-repeated even digit numbers, 6 of these. For the all even digited numbers 2*2*1=4 out of the 2*3*3=18 do not have repetition so we exclude another 14.

We excluded 9+9+6+14=38 numbers. Hence our final solution is 90-38=52 numbers.

Comment: But that does not account for repetition, does it? If you count 5 choices in the hundreds digit, and 6 in the tens digit, you could repeat digits.

Comment: @Nasenhaar I have edited the solution to account for it now.

Comment: I was exactly asking what you all have answered. Thanks to all of you and sorry for inconvenience occurred.

Answer (score 0):

How many even 3 digits numbers can be formed, with no repetition,  using 0,1,2,3,4,5 ?

\begin{array}{cccccr} 
   E & E & E & \to 2 \times 2 \times 1 &= & 4 \\
   E & O & E & \to 2 \times 3 \times 2 &= & 12 \\
   O & E & E & \to 3 \times 3 \times 2 &= & 18 \\
   O & O & E & \to 3 \times 2 \times 3 &= & 18 \\
\end{array}

Total number of ways = $52$

How many even 3 digits numbers can be formed, with repetition,  using 0,1,2,3,4,5 ?

\begin{array}{cccccr} 
   E & E & E & \to 2 \times 3 \times 3 &= & 18 \\
   E & O & E & \to 2 \times 3 \times 3 &= & 18 \\
   O & E & E & \to 3 \times 3 \times 3 &= & 27 \\
   O & O & E & \to 3 \times 3 \times 3 &= & 27 \\
\end{array}

Total number of ways = $90$